Reading a CSV from a Private GitHub Repo in a Deployed Shiny App
I have an R Shiny application that currently draws on a .csv file as its main data source. That file sits in the app's folder, so that when I deploy the app to shinyapps.io with RSConnect, it uploads with it. The problem is that I then have to redeploy the entire app if I have any updates to the back-end data file.
A workaround I'm thinking SHOULD work is to make the read.csv line in the setup of the app's code look to a csv file I have pushed to a GitHub repository. Where I have come up short in my own online research is that the repo needs to be Private, so I need to pass some sort of authentication with it. But all of what I can find online is for downloading whole packages from GitHub and stuff like that, not reading single files.
And I know you can just read.csv("raw file link") for public repos, but when I do that and try to deploy to shinyapps.io, the app just crashes because it says it can't authenticate.
I have also already allowed authentication/access to GitHub from shinyapps.io AND to shinyapps.io from GitHub. Hoping I'm just missing a stored token or something of that nature.

Try to use PINS package to post the data (csv to rda) to Posit_Board(), and your app should use the data in the Posit_Board().  This way you can update the data in the Posit_Board() whenever you need to and the app uses the latest data.  No need to redeploy.

Unfortunately, after looking into it, that would be awesome except that it requires a Posit Connect subscription, which we do not have. I saw a free way would be to set it up with Google drive, but I'm trying to avoid that because I've had issues in the past with Drive and the API dying after getting hit too many times too quickly. Is there a free option somewhere in that package?

Yes, it does require Posit Connect subscription.  I am not aware of any free option.

I am doing a similar thing (although reading multiple image files from private Github repo). I used the httr package. I am able to drop a new image in Github and it appears in my Shiny app.
I have a file in the app folder that I push to Shiny called .httr-oauth. Authentication may be done by using the code here:
https://github.com/r-lib/httr/blob/main/demo/oauth2-github.r
In the code below, replace the Github_Account_Name and the Repo_Name with the actual ones from your Github account. These will be in the URL when the repo is open in a browser. GET returns an object that includes the path to the repo, as well as the names of each file in the repo, and other stuff.
I didn't write this code, but it works and I'm not sure of the details.
library(httr)
req <- GET("https://api.github.com/repos/Github_Account_Name/Repo_Name/git/trees/main?recursive=1")
stop_for_status(req)
filelist <- unlist(lapply(content(req)$tree, "[", "path"), use.names = F)
mypics <- list()
for(i in 1:length(filelist)) {
    fn <- paste0("https://raw.github.com/Github_Account_Name/Repo_Name/main/", filelist[i])
    mypics$pics[[i]] <- magick::image_read(fn)
}


See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41696199/authentication-to-github-private-repositories-with-httr

A couple questions and apologies since I'm a bit new to the API/web hosting world. First, where you've got {insert path here}, is that the path to the full repo? To the raw data file? Second, I'm not sure where the authentication building part of that issue linked is, is there anyway someone could isolate that code?

I've edited to answer your questions.

I realized my previous answer was reading from a public GitHub repo.
Here is how to read a file from a private Github repo
Note that this method requires you to send your GitHub Personal Access Token (PAT) to Shinyapps. Therefore we will use a fine-grained token to limit access to only the repo that contains the data. Is this secure? I don't know.

Create a private Github repo and place your file data there. The data file in my example code is DataTest.dat. (It's really a .csv).

Generate a fine-grained GitHub Personal Access Token (PAT) for that repo:
a. Go to your Github account settings (not repo settings):  Settings --> Developer Settings --> Personal Access Token --> Fine-Grained Token --> Generate New Token
b. If you have 2FA set up you may have to enter a 2FA code here.
c. Name the token, choose the expiration date, and select the repo that the token grants access to.
d. Select the appropriate permissions (since I only READ data from my repo, under Repository Permissions I set Actions and Contents to  "read-only").
e. Click Generate Token and copy it.
f. Create an .Renviron file in your Shiny app folder to hold your Github token. Call it GITHUB_PAT:
GITHUB_PAT=github_pat_78s6fads6f7asd6f7a6sd767sd6f7as6d7fasd7f7asd76f7adf67

Deploy your app including the .Renviron file.


Use this code in your app to authenticate:
library(shiny)
library(here)
library(readr)

# Create GitHub path
repo_owner <- "Your_Github_Name"
repo_name <- "Your_Repo_Name"
repo_file <- "DataTest.dat"
branch <- "main"

url <- paste0(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/",
  repo_owner, "/", repo_name, "/", branch, "/", repo_file
)

# Authenticate with the PAT
library(httr)
github_pat <- Sys.getenv("GITHUB_PAT")
response <- GET(
  url,
  authenticate(user = "", password = github_pat)
)

# Check response and read the data
if (response$status_code == 200) {
  data <- read_csv(content(response, "text"))
} else {
  stop("Failed to fetch data: ", response$status_code)
}

